# Acquiring multiple values from one select option value. PHP HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

How do I have acquire multiple values from one select option value.
An example here,

```
<html>

<form method="post" action="#">
   <select name="retrive_destination">
       <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    $destinationID = $row['destinationID'];
                    $destination_place = $row['destination_place'];
                    echo '<option value="'.$destinationID.'">'.$destination_place.'</option>
       ?>
      <input type="submit">
</select>

</form>
</html>
```

How do i get both values '$destinationID' and '$destination_place' from one option value , when the form i submitted as i need both values when the user selects an option on the next step. THank you guys cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compose the two values and then explode them server-side

```
<html>

<form method="post" action="#">
   <select name="retrive_destination">
       <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    $destinationID = $row['destinationID'];
                    $destination_place = $row['destination_place'];
                    echo '<option value="'.$destinationID."_".htmlentities($destination_place).'">'.$destination_place.'</option>
       ?>
      <input type="submit">
</select>

</form>
</html>
```

Php server-side

```
$value= $_REQUEST['retrive_destination'];
$explode=explode("_",$value,2);
$destinationID =$explode[0];
$destination_place =$explode[1];
```

Comment: This is what I was going to put as an answer, you may want to include the explode statement as well in case he doesn't know how to use it.

Comment: Also put a dot between $destination_place'">'

Comment: Edited the answer as suggested

Comment: Even though concatenating the value to ID is an easy method, you need to be careful, since the $destination_place looks like a Text entity and can contain quotes or > < symbols, so have to encode these

Comment: Thank you @Piancentecristian. the explode worked excellently. this was blast.

Comment: I have values from database in select. code is same above but value is $id, and it's not working, can you help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Jquery Version:

Add an input type hidden on your form:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
<select name="retrive_destination" id="des">
   <option value="1">Ibiza</option>
   <option value="2">Mallorca</option>
   <option value="3">Chile</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="destination" id="dest"/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#des").change(function(){
   $("#dest").val($("#des option:selected").text());  
});
});
```

PHP:

```
$destId  = $_POST['retrive_destination'];
$destVal = $_POST['destination'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Best is to have the form only submit the ID as you can always fetch the destination place from database in your server side.